# Python: How do I keep a converted string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to keep a string I've converted from an integer. I can convert an int variable into a string, but then I can't seem to interact with that. Here's how it goes in the Python shell:

```
a = 100
a
>>> 100
str(a)
>>> '100'
a
>>> 100
str(a) = b
>>> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

What I need is to turn this '100' string into a new variable. I've tried searching; the answer is probably out there, but I'm clearly not using the right search terms. All the answers I've found have only been concerned with how to convert from one type to another.

Comment: don't you mean `b = str(a)`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are experiencing is not the problem that you think you are experiencing.

When you define a variable in Python, the variable goes on the left of the equals sign.  It should look like this:

```
b = str(a)
```

This will define *b* without giving you an error message.  Going back to your question, if you want to change *a* to a string and keep it that way, *str(a)* will not suffice. Instead:

```
a = str(a)
```

Will change your variable to a string.  *str(a)* is simply a function that returns the variable *a* in the form of a string.  If you do not redefine *a* here, *str(a)* will not return to anywhere and your string will be lost.

Comment: Did you just copy Martijn's answer? (No, I don't really believe that, but they look very similiar...)

Comment: No, in fact his only addressed the backward syntax before I posted.  I also began my comment before he posted.

Answer (score 1):

You have your assignment syntax back to front. The target name goes *on the left*:

```
b = str(a)
```

Now `b` is a reference to the return value of `str()`.

You can also re-assign back to `a`, replacing the old integer value with the string representation:

```
a = str(a)
```

Your attempt instead tried to use `str(a)` as an assignment target; Python can't let you do that because the result of `str(a)` is unknown when the code is compiled; you cannot bind any object to another, you need to have a reference instead (so a name, or an attribute, or a list index, or a dictionary key, etc.).